Replacement transistor for a radiation detector
I am trying to reproduce this circuit from "Elektor" issue 06/2011, page 22, by Burkhard Kainka:

I replaced the two transistors with SS9014C. Is that a good choice?
From testing, it seems there is no signal amplification. In order to see if it amplifies, I used a simple voltage divider in place of the photodiode.

Mihai8 - Hi, I see you stated that "Elektor" was the source of the schematic. As explained in the site rule on referencing, we should all reference to the best of our ability. Can you improve that reference? I know most issues of the magazine are not available online legally, but can you state the specific issue number/date? The author of that specific article? etc etc TY

Mihai8 - Hi again, Although another site member has kindly improved the reference I mentioned in my previous comment, I won't delete these comments yet, to ensure you see them and the expectations around the site referencing rule. If I delete the comments now, you might never see them and therefore you might not see that explanation. Please reply with a brief comment when you've read this, then I'll delete relevant comments. TY || @JRE - Thanks for improving the reference.


I replaced these two transistors with SS9014C. Is a good choice?

Honestly? No. The BC549 is about the most cheap and available transistor on earth. It's hard to imagine you can source a photon detector, but not a BC549C. So, you modified a known-to-work analog circuit that was probably hand-tuned for a while, to replace an ancient transistor with one that is slightly less ancient, but worse, and, due to being less ubiquitous and technologically "bad" still declared obsolete by the manufacturer.
Is it a feasible replacement?
Maybe: it depends, you'll have to do the math. The BC549C has a higher DC gain (hFE,\$\beta\$ ) for all but very small collector currents. Grab the datasheets of the SS9014C and of the BC549C (maybe from Fairchild and On SEMI, to keep it in the same company) and compare the graphs for "DC current gain".
Look up the gain at the bias current your circuit imposes (for that, mentally remove D1 and all capacitors from your schematic, and do the classical large signal analysis you do for transistors). That works with two transistors as well (they are operating in different points, so don't make the mistake of assuming the same \$\beta\$ for both). Or, you just hammer the circuit with BC549C into a circuit simulator, and see which currents flow into the collectors, and how high the current gain is. Any circuit simulator under the sun supports the BC549C – again, probably the most ubiquitous discrete through-hole transistor ever. Then, use these currents to look up the DC current gains in the SS9014 datasheet. If they're the same or higher, you're fine, if they're lower, you might need to reduce collector resistors until you achieve the same sensitivity.
Personally, I think you have something that's likely to work, with slight twiddling; your replacement is not that much worse than a BC549C, probably, and it can have a slightly higher bandwidth if operated at higher currents than your circuit does.
It is a nice little tidy circuit that shows how you can do simple "event" detectors with a minimum number of components.
Were I to build a detector myself, I'd probably go with a different circuit, where I'd make sure to use an amplifier model that loads the reverse-biased photo diode as little as possible while having a bandwidth that is as high as possible to not miss any detections. Such a circuit would be

using an opamp instead of discrete transistors, to enable high gain, high bandwidth
using FET inputs instead of BJT to reduce the loading of the photodiode
have adjustable gain so that I can adjust sensitivity

Such a circuit would be the classical transimpedance amplifier opamp configuration with the photodiode in reverse bias; in other words, something like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I don't have a really well-researched Opamp type recommendation for you here. I guess a OPA355 would make for a rather high-bandwidth detector there.

The SS9014C has slightly lower gain than the BC549C.  That would reduce the senstivity of the detector circuit.
The real problem is that your voltage divider isn't a good simulation of radiation detection.  T2, R5, and C2 are intended to react to sharp pulses from the photodiode, not to a fixed voltage.  T1 is intended to react to changes in the current through D1.
The transistors may be fine - except for the gain and the bandwidth they are pretty close.  It is just that you can't test the circuit the way you are going at it.
